# SQL Developer crashes every time I open it

Tags: crash, oracle-sqldeveloper

My OS is windows 10 pro x64 and I installed the java sql developer Windows 64-bit with JDK 9 included.

**What I have done :**
I extracted the file into the desktop and I opened the .exe file. A message told me that I should use jdk 8 or 9, so I went to appdata to find the "product" file and I changed the path so now it's pointed to the jdk that was within the sql developer file.

**The issue I have :**
When I first agreed for using the jdk 10, the loading bar got stuck. Since I moved the path for the right jdk, it worked. The problem now is that immediately after the openning, it closes itself. So I don't know what to do to solve this problem. My drivers are all up to date.

Comment: point to a Java 8 home - java 9 on some windows has issues (on the java side with javaFX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by doing this, maybe it will help someone in the future :
- Download jdk 8 from oracle
- Go to the sqlDeveloper folder on appData and find the "product" file.
- Open it and set the path to the new jdk you've just downloaded.
- Erase the other sqlDeveloper folder on appData with the "tmp" & systemXX.XX... folders on it.
- Start sqldeveloper

Comment: This bit shouldn't be necessary: Erase the other sqlDeveloper folder on appData with the "tmp" & systemXX.XX... folders on it.